# How to exclude when both values are 0 in calculating Kendall Tau and Pearson corr coeff with p-values in a for loop?

Tags: python, loops, correlation

My data is consist of 400 food items (in columns) with its nutrient values (rows). Sample data is as following:

```
    import pandas as pd 
    fooddb = {'food':['oat','barley','rice','sorghumn'], 'x':[0,0,0.7,0.6], 'y':[0, 1, 0.5, 0], 'z':[0, 0.5, 0.3, 0]}
    df=pd.DataFrame(fooddb, columns = ['food','x','y','z'])
    df = df.set_index('food')
```

Here, I'm trying to get Kendall's tau with p-value and Pearson correlation coeff with p-value of each food pair among 400 food items. I figured out how to make combination pairs of all 400 food items, yet failed to make successful codes in some parts.
First, I want to consider x and y values that are  (x>0,y>0) or (x>=0 and y>0) or (x>0 and y>=0) in calculating correlation. So I came up with

```
    if (value[i].sum(axis=1) >0 :

    if (ind[i] + ind[j] > 0) :
```

and many other similar codes, but all didn't work out.

Second, I want to use stats.kendalltau( ) in the loop, but NaN was keep showing up. So, replaced with corr(method='kendall') which does not have p-value.

Right now, I have the following code:

```
    rows, cols = DF_T.shape
    colname = list(DF_T.columns)
    value = DF_T.values
    corr = DF_T.corr(method='kendall').values
    pear = DF_T.corr(method='pearson').values
    kendall_data = []
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(i+1, cols):
            if (value[i].sum(axis=1) >0 :
                tau=corr[i,j]
                pea=pear[i,j]
                t,p= stats.kendalltau(i,j,nan_policy='omit')
                x_kendall=colname[i]
                y_kendall=colname[j]
                kendall_data.append((x_kendall,y_kendall,tau,pea,t))
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data for a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @MatthewBorish I uploaded a sample dataframe. Thanks for letting me know!